# Updating PHP Live

Tags: php, html

So I have a download button, which records the amount of times it clicked and updates the number in a txt file. That number is then displayed on the index.php
Is there a way that I can have that number updating every 5 seconds with out the whole page refreshing? ( I have read lots of other posts, but I don't understand them )

http://go-create.net ( You can view page source if you want to see the code I have used )

Thanks,

Jack
EDIT: A little bit like the live updating number of downloads on http://minecraft.net but it doesn't need to have a nice number change animation )

Comment: Storing data in a text file is a bad practise. You better use database such as MySQL to store data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for you question invloves jQuery to pull a request of a PHP script on your server. In example below, a PHP script is called every 5 seconds. `check_clicks.php` receives `item_id` via GET method, processes it as needed and echoes the result which we get in `data`

```
(function update_clicks() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/check_clicks.php',
        data: {item_id: item_id},
        complete: function (data) {
            $('#result_div').html(data);
            setTimeout(update_clicks, 5000);
        }
    });
})();
```

---

`check_clicks.php`

Lets say you have a table called `download_stats`. You table is arranged like

```
item_id | clicks
--------+-------
      1 |    56
```

To retrieve click amount you need to perform a query

```
$db = //your database connection here
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT clicks FROM download_stats WHERE item_id = '$_GET['item_id']' LIMIT 1");`
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)
{
    echo $data['clicks'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you but what should /check_clicks.php include on the page?

Comment: @GoCreate as to my comment under OP, `check_clicks.php` supposed to contain SQL query to retrieve amount of button clicks from database

Comment: So I am creating a data base with two fields, but there are all of these options: TypeDocumentation,
Length/Values1,  
Default2, 
Collation, 
Attributes,  
Null,  
Index,  
AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Comments and I have no clue what to put for them. Do I just leave them all blank?

Comment: You can add an autoincrement field such as `entry_id`; and both `item_id` and `clicks` are of INT type

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax to do this, which is rather easy to use with jQuery

for example:

```
$.ajax({
url: '/number.php'
success: function(response){
$('div#number').text(response)};
});
```

number.php is a script that returns the number you want to display. div#number references the html-element which you want to update. To use jQuery, you have to include the jQuery-library.